# How to install Ubuntu beside W10 on 2nd disk without efi?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I try to install Ubuntu for the first time but I have a problem.

[There are my partitions here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss5Vg.png)

I want to install Ubuntu on the grey part of my disque 0, but when I try to install, I go to the manual partitioning menu, I add root partition, home partition and swap partition.

But I can't install. Any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: First, I would recommend keeping everything in one partition if this is your first install. Ubuntu will create a swapfile for you when you install, so it will handle that for you. If you only make one partition and choose to install here, it will not setup EFI. if you make an EFI system partition, it will automatically setup EFI.

Comment: You also need to format the target installation disk as GPT or DOS and the partition type should be ext4.

Comment: But I have all my files on :D disk and Window is on :C, I cant' install Ubuntu in a little place of the :D?

Comment: You will have to delete :D and partition it in the Ubuntu installer. :D is already formatted, so you can't install onto "a little piece of the :D".

Comment: You have enough free space on disk0 to install Ubuntu. "D:" is just a partition on disk0, regardless of what Microsoft calls it, so you can add up to three more partitions with a dos partition table, or 100+ with gpt. Adding partitions should not affect the ntfs D: partition at all.